# why dot character is not encoded in my url?

Tags: javascript, url, urlencode

I am trying to encode a param string passed in a url with the javascript function :encodeURIComponent
My param is  T.24,15

`endodeURIComponent(param)` gives me :

> T.24%2C15

, but I am expecting it to return

> T%2E24%2C15

The dot symbol is not encoded, I don't understand why.

Does anyone know?

Comment: *Why* would you have the dot encoded ?

Answer (score 4):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

> encodeURIComponent escapes all characters except the following:
>   alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )

Only the characters that could prevent the URI transmission or parsing are encoded. There's no reason to encode the dot.

Answer (score 0):

For example, Rails uses the dot for formatting:

```
domain.com/article/5/show.json
```

would cause the framework to respond as json, if configured.